# Java Swing drop down list

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener, dropdownlistfor

I have created a drop down list using JAVA Swing. When I select "Keep track of status of RCM:", I want to create another drop down list next to the option selected. should I use mouseactionlistener instead?   I trying to accomplish something like in this, when I click menu options, there is another list which I can select under menu options category.  Example : http://smoothjazztampabay.com/wp-content/rockettheme/rt_metropolis_wp/menu-options/dropdownmenu.jpg

I tried using this code but couldn't.

```
         if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {
            ItemSelectable itemS = itemEvent.getItemSelectable();
            String cmd = selectedString(itemS);
            if ( cmd.equals("Keep track of status of RCM:"))
            {
                RCMCombo2.addItem(RCMCombo);
                selectionPanel.add(RCMCombo2);
            }
```

The full version of the code is shown as below:

```
    String [] RCM2 = {"Keep track of status of RCM:", "Add and activate RCM", "Remove RCM", 
     "Display the usage statistics for RCM", 
"Update capabilities of RCMs", "Show RCM used most frequently in the last n days",
"Display number of times the RCM was emptied in n hours"};


RCMCombo2 = new JComboBox(RCM2); 
RCMCombo2.addItemListener(itemListener);  
    RCMCombo2.setEditable(false);
    RCMCombo2.setBounds(10,10,10,30);

    //"Updates capabilities of RCM"); Get the location of RCM");

    selectionPanel.add(RCMCombo2);

ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() 
{
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) 
      {
        int state = itemEvent.getStateChange();
        //System.out.println((state == ItemEvent.SELECTED) ? "Selected" : "Deselected");
        //System.out.println("Item: " + itemEvent.getItem());
        if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {
            ItemSelectable itemS = itemEvent.getItemSelectable();
            String cmd = selectedString(itemS);
            if ( cmd.equals("Keep track of status of RCM:"))
            {
                RCMCombo2.addItem(RCMCombo2);
                selectionPanel.add(RCMCombo2);
            }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There is no "JAVA GUI". You are obviously using Java Swing.

Comment: `selectionPanel.add(RCMCombo2);` Try and `revalidate` and `repaint` after this.

Comment: Seems that `revalidate();repaint()` problem =(. Also seems you need to set bounds to your `RCMCombo2`.

Comment: Maybe give a quick synopsis of what you're trying to accomplish with this task. It may not be the most desirable solution.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are on a completely wrong track. I think you are mixing the usage of `ItemListener` with the setup of the lists model.
Check out this [guide to ComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) - it should contain all the information you need.

Comment: I tried to use combo box, but I wanted to create another drop down list when an item in the combo box is selected.

Comment: should I use mouseactionlistener instead? and I have added this combo box in the selection panel. I trying to accomplish something like in this, when I click menu options, there is another list which I can select under menu options category. http://smoothjazztampabay.com/wp-content/rockettheme/rt_metropolis_wp/menu-options/dropdownmenu.jpg

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is a [list selection listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) on your "outer" combobox that in its event handler changes the model of the "inner" combobox. After the model is changed you will have to trigger a repaint as mentioned in the comments above.